# Different numbers of rows when importing csv

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb

I ran into a problem that I didn't understand. I have a .csv file that is about 10 GB in size. I'm transferring it into the database. When I use only the innodb engine, 1.863.941 lines are added. But when I use the Aria engine, 1.765.972 lines are added.

I can't see how many rows there are in this one because it is so big .csv file.

The database I use: **Mysql 5.7.24 - Mariadb 10.3.12**

The SQL Command I use:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "'.$file.'"
        INTO TABLE '.$table.'
        CHARACTER SET UTF8
        FIELDS TERMINATED by \',\'
        ENCLOSED BY \'"\'
        LINES TERMINATED BY \'\r\n\''
```

I am not getting any error code when transferring SQL.

Comment: How are you determining the number of lines added? If you are looking at a count of rows using SQL know that some of the database engines provide an estimate of the number of rows.

Comment: I'm looking at the number of queries on Phpmyadmin.

Comment: If you run `mysql` directly and query the 2 tables using `count(*)` what values do they have?

Comment: .First result aria: 1765972;Elapsed time : 17 Sec , Second result innodb: 1863941;Elapsed time : 38 Sec

Comment: I am using it when importing. https://github.com/sanathp/largecsv2mysql

Comment: You should be able to run `wc -l` on your file to find out the number of rows.

Comment: I'd suggest doing it yourself directly in MySQL.